# Split value of a variable to multiple variables

Tags: sas

i have a variable with values (14 12 13 15 15 14). i need to create new variables and assign the value accordingly Example: value 14 in var14 and value 2 in Var2

Answer (score 0):

data a;
input a1 @@;
cards;
14 12 13 15 15 14
;
run;
%macro m;
proc sql noprint;
select distinct a1 into :k separated by '@' from WORK.a;
select count(distinct a1) into :c from WORK.a;
quit;
%do i=1 %to &c;
    %let var%scan(&k, &i, '@')=%scan(&k, &i, '@');
    %put var%scan(&k, &i, '@');
%end;
%mend m;
%m;

**************Log Results***************
var12
var13
var14
var15